# Eigenvalues of $S$ - understanding the argument

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

Let $M$ be a $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrix such that $M^{2} = I_{2}$ (the $2\times 2$ identity matrix) and define:
$$S = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
M & 0 \\
0 & M 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
a $4 \times 4$ matrix. I want to prove that $S$ has eigenvalues $\{\pm \frac{1}{2}\}$ and $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(S \pm \frac{1}{2}) = 2$. The argument goes as follows. Since $M^{2} = I_{2}$ and $M \neq I_{2}$, it follows that the eigenvalues of $M$ are $\{\pm 1\}$, with multiplicity of each eigenvalue being one. By this fact, the definition of $S$ and the invariance of spectrum, one obtains the results.

Now, I want to better understand the argument.

(1) The first part of the argument proves that the eigenvalues of $M$ are $\{\pm 1\}$. Since $M^{2} = I_{2}$ is Hermitian, then $M^{\dagger} = M = M^{-1}$, so $M$ is unitary. As a consequence, the eigenvalues of $M$ have absolute value $|\lambda| = \pm 1$. Moreover, since $M$ is Hermitian, it must have only real-valued eigenvalues, and this implies $\lambda = \pm 1$. I believe this is the reasoning behind the first part of the argument. However, why do we need $M \neq I_{2}$? And also, why can we conclude that the multiplicity of each eigenvalue is one?

(b) I don't quite understand the second part of the argument. How should I use the unitary invariance of the spectrum to obtain the eigenvalues of $S$? And why is $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(S \pm \frac{1}{2}) = 2$?

Comment: You use some strange notation. $\ker(S \pm \frac 12) = 2$ does not make sense because $\ker(A)$ (the kernel of $A$) is a subspace, not a number. Perhaps you mean to say that the **dimension** of the kernel is $2$. Similarly, $M = \{\pm 1\}$ doesn't make sense because $M$ is a matrix, perhaps you mean that the **eigenvalues** of $M$ are $\pm 1$.

Comment: Ops. That was my mistake. I'm going to edit it! Thanks!

Comment: Also, the statement that you are trying to prove is incorrect as stated. It is not enough to have $M \neq I_2$, we must also know that $M \neq -I_2$

Comment: @BenGrossmann I edited the post with the corrections. You were right on your observations.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I don't know why we need $M \neq \pm I_{2}$ tho.

Comment: Try plugging in $M = -I_2$ and see what eigenvalues you get

Comment: You get all four eigenvalues $-1$ if $M = -I_{2}$ and all of them $+1$ if $M = I_{2}$. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question/remark:** "Now, I want to better understand the argument."

**Response:** Assume $Mv=\lambda v$ for some scalar $\lambda$ and $v \neq 0$. It follows

$$v=Iv=M^2v=M(Mv)=M(\lambda v)=\lambda(Mv)=\lambda^2v$$

hence $\lambda^2=1$ and $\lambda =1,-1$. You get two non-zero eigenvectors $u,v$ with

$$Mu=u, Mv=-v$$

and 4 eigen vectors for $S$: $v_1:=(u,0),v_2:=(v,0),v_3:=(0,u),v_4:=(0,v)$ with eigen value $\pm \frac{1}{2}$.The matrix $S\pm\frac{1}{2}$ has kernel $v_1,v_3$ or $v_2,v_4$, hence $ker(S\pm\frac{1}{2})$ has dimension $2$.